# Can Spike, Tournament Grinder tutor for cards outside of your Sideboard at Launch Night's Draft?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

[image: Spike, Tournament Grinder]

Will tutoring with [Spike, Tournament Grinder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439458)'s ability still have to follow the ruling that anything outside of the game refers to sideboard only? If so, isn't this a useless ability since every card one drafts is legal to play with? Or will there be an exception where one can tutor for a Constructed format banned card outside the game that one has in procession that they have brought that night?

Comment: @TheThirdMan This seems to be asking for clarification on the meaning of "a card you own", as opposed to the other question which is asking for clarification of "has been banned or restricted in a Constructed format". I don't think the question is a duplicate. (BTW Jason I don't think your edit really makes that any more clear than it was before - but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: @DavidZ: Convincing enough... I edited the question myself to hopefully indicate that more clearly (the title in particular was quite misleading).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which cards can Spike, Tournament Grinder tutor for?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39102/which-cards-can-spike-tournament-grinder-tutor-for)

Comment: @JoeW See the comment I posted above as a reply to the last person who voted to make this a duplicate of that question. (I've edited the title of that question to more closely reflect what it's asking, to avoid potential confusion about this.)

Answer (score 3):

**You are able to to get cards outside of your sideboard using Spike's ability in both limited and constructed.**

This is adressed by Mark Rosewater (The person in charge of silver bordered rulings) on his tumblr [Blogatog](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/).

> **bolas-our-lord-and-savior asked: In un limited/constructed spike can get cards not in your sideboard right?**
>
> MR:Yes.

[Source](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/167495238808/in-un-limitedconstructed-spike-can-get-cards-not).

---

## Special note for Commander/EDH play:

With the announcement that [Silver-boarded cards will be legal in Commander/EDH](http://mtgcommander.net/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18749) until January 15 2018, it should be mentioned that Spike will not work without prior agreement from your play group ([as confirmed by Mark Rosewater](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/post/168131446968/mark-you-dont-understand-the-commander-rules-on)). This is because [Commander already has an established rules](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php) for cards that refer to cards outside the game.

> **13.** Abilities which refer to other cards owned outside the game (Wishes, Spawnsire, Research, Ring of Ma'ruf) do not function in Commander without prior agreement on their scope from the playgroup.

The common way that this is resolved is with the use of a [Wishboard](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Wishboard).

Comment: Interesting that he says this applies to constructed, seeing as Un-cards aren't legal in any constructed formats...

Comment: @TheThirdMan He is probably talking about casual Constructed, as silver boarders are primarily intended for casual play.

Comment: True, but "ruling" silver-bordered cards in casual play is kind of pointless, seeing as you already chose to disregard Wizard's better judgement and included them in your decks (and even worse, let your friends do the same! :D ). Also, as I stated in my answer, casual play doesn't need an extra ruling - you're already allowed to use every card from your collection.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Having an official ruling does help for casual play though, as MaRo's rulings can be used as "evidence" to support one side and end arguments/disagreements among players.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Un cards are currently officially legal in EDH/Commander (until at least January 15), and unstable itself has rules for constructed use of contraptions. The ability would be very restricted if it was not able to go outside the sideboard, since it would need to grab a card that is legal in the format played, but banned in another format.

Comment: @Andrew There is a Rule that applys to commander play specifically that neuters Spike fairly heavily. Rule 13 will says that you will need to discuss how the card works with your play group first.

Comment: @Malco Yes there is, but I'd wager generally play groups would agree with rulings from MaRo. I was specifically responding to TheThirdMan saying that un cards are not legal in any constructed format, which is not true, as they are legal in commander, which is an official constructed format.

Comment: @Andrew The answer is already a bit bloated now with the commander note but I will drop the MaRo ruling as well. When TheThirdMan (and the orginal Q and A) were posted the EDH committee had not yet made their announcement. It was quite the surprise when they did as it was unprecedented to bring silver boarders into official constructed formats.

Comment: @Malco Fair point, but it bears mentioning that the comment is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The rule you're referring to applies to sanctioned events exclusively, as indicated for example by [Spawnsire of Ulamog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpawnsire%20of%20Ulamog%5d)'s Rulings:

> In a casual game, the cards you cast from outside the game come from your personal collection. In a sanctioned event, those cards must come from your sideboard. (...)

From what I can gather from the [official product page](https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/unstable), there will be sanctioned drafts, which means the above rule will indeed prevent you from searching anything else but the cards in your Sideboard (meaning that you drafted, but didn't include in your deck), and as you correctly stated, there won't likely be any banned or restricted cards to find there, as the set itself is legal during it's own draft.

As you said yourself, **this sounds like a case that will be handled by the Release Notes**, which are yet to be publicised. Seeing as Un-cards are meant to be exciting and bending the rules as far as possible, it seems to be in the spirit of the set to ignore this restriction and actually be able to search for your [Time Walk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Walk%5d) if you choose to do so. After all, with a set like this, there will be crazier things happening, and a 1/1 with CMC 4 isn't quite worth the pick otherwise.

Whether the release notes will account for that case or not, **you could address the head judge and ask them to allow cards outside of the sideboard as well**, as they have the authority to rule one way or another if in doubt. While this would be questionable in any other tournament if it went explicitly against what the release notes say, I personally wouldn't mind for a set like this, and I think most players partaking in tournaments like that would expect a less serious athmosphere from the beginning, and/or are enjoying more crazyness.

Comment: Thank you and yes I do believe your edit of my original question is more fitting. Now to your answer, I thank you for letting me know that no further notes were released yet. I hope they will allow some fun and crazy shenanigans with it on release. I also did not know the judge watching the event could make changes like that. I cannot wait for Unstable to release.